# Remove quotation mark from python list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a file with items like this:-

```
0 -> 205,3
1 -> 0,110,18,49,8
```

I need to convert to a dictionary:-

```
{0:[205,3],
 1:[0,110,18,49,8]}
```

I tried:-

```
def read_input(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    g = defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(' -> ')
        g[int(line[0])].append(line[1])
    return g
```

My result:-

```
defaultdict(list,
            {0: ['205,3'],
             1: ['0,110,18,49,8']})
```

I also tried:-

```
def read_input(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    g = defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(' -> ')
        g[int(line[0])].append(int(x) for x in line[1].split(','))
    return g
```

Result:-

```
defaultdict(list,
            {0: [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x110e01410>],
             1: [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x110e01460>]})
```

Comment: Not a duplicate. I checked ot the solutions and it doesn't help my case. Please elaborate more.

Comment: Use can use the bultin `type` method to look at what data-type different objects are.  The reason you have quotation marks is because your objects are strings -- because they were read in from a text file.  You need to convert them to integers which is exactly what the other solution describes.  You are *correctly* casting `line[0]` into an integer, but you are not casting `line[1]` into an integer --- it is still a string.

Comment: I tried the other solution and posted my result here. It didn't help me.

Comment: You need to enclose your [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in brackets for it to work right:  `[int(x) for x in line[1].split(',')]`.   It is a good procedure to try to understand the solutions you are implementing.

Comment: You should be using a [with](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement to handle your file